# How to render multiple livewire component as string?

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, livewires

I have multiple livewire components e.g. `opd.patient-count, opd.visit-count, opd.checkup-count` and so on. I would like to store these components name into database then call by user role. Anyway, It does not work once I tried as below.

```
   foreach ...

    echo '<livewire:opd.patient-count />';

   endforeach ...
```

Any advice or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Can you post how are you storing the livewire component into database ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand your problem, You can achieve using this syntax instead

```
@foreach($components as $eachComponent)
  @livewire($eachComponent,['componentData' => $data])
@endforeach
```

in this code above, the component name is assigned accordingly using a blade `@foreach` directive and iterate over each element and make the component.

Comment: Dear MANSOOR KOCHY, thanks.

Comment: You are always welcome